# How to upload file in jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
package net.codejava.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Name of the directory where uploaded files will be saved, relative to
     * the web application directory.
     */
    private static final String SAVE_DIR = "uploadFiles";

    /**
     * handles file upload
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets absolute path of the web application
        String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
        String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;

        // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
     */
    private String extractFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}









<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="UploadServlet"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>




<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${requestScope.message}</h2>
</body>
</html>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>FileUploadServletExample</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <display-name>FileUploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.codejava.upload.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>upload.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I've got this code from somewhere I've added the required jar files Apache Common File Upload 1.2.2 and Apache Commons IO 2.3 but still not working says:

> The requested resource (/UploadFile/FileUploadServlet) is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotation @WebServlet("/UploadServlet") do not match with the url-pattern in web.xml(i.e /uploadfile).

Therefore, I suggest you to remove the remove the entry of web.xml for your Servlet as you are using annotations there is no need of entry in web.xml and another tting is in your jsp file make following changes:

```
<form method="post" action="/UploadServlet"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
```